# Join 2 foreign key relationships into one object in query

Tags: android, android-room

Given

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "state",
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(entity = Foo::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("foo_id")),
        ForeignKey(entity = Bar::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("bar_id"))
    )
)
data class State(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 1
) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "foo_id")
    var fooId: Long? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bar_id")
    var barId: Long? = null

}

@Entity(tableName = "foo")
open class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    open val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "foo")
    val foo: String?,
)

@Entity(tableName = "bar")
open class Bar(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    open val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bar")
    val bar: String?,
)
```

I am trying to create a Join POJO to store the results of the query:

```
class FooBar(
    @Embedded
    val foo: Foo,

    @Embedded
    val bar: Bar
)
```

And my failed attempt at a query:

```
@Query("SELECT foo.*, bar.* FROM foo, bar JOIN state ON foo.id == state.foo_id JOIN bar ON bar.id == session.bar_id ")
fun getFooBar(): LiveData<FooBar>
```

However I get an error when compiling.  Do I need to deconflict the id fields in foo and bar since they are named the same?

I have tried with a prefix, no luck:

```
class FooBar(
    @Embedded(prefix = "foo_")
    val foo: Foo,

    @Embedded(prefix = "bar_")
    val bar: Bar
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you.

```
@Query("SELECT RoomArticle.*, RoomBranch.id AS 'RoomBranch_id', RoomBranch.name AS 'RoomBranch_name' "
```

Data entity:

```
public class RoomArticleOfBranch {
    @Embedded
    public RoomArticle article;
    @Embedded(prefix = "RoomBranch_")
    public RoomBranch branch;
```

Notice I provide prefix both in query and in `@Embedded`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying Embedded try to change the query as follows

```
@Dao
interface TestDao {
    @Query("SELECT foo.id as foo_id,bar.id as bar_id,bar.bar as bar_bar FROM foo, bar JOIN state ON foo_id = state.foo_id and bar_id = state.bar_id")
    fun getFooBar(): LiveData<FooBar>
}
```

There are two things need to be fixed.

1. You need to rename the column name during the select query.
2. fixing your joining query.